# adding validation message at the registration page

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am using `make:auth` to make my validation for the registration, laravel also gave the validation message whenever my input is not authenticated, but that's because it uses the default design by laravel, since i'm using my own design of registration page, i want to also add the validation message using the one laravel gave, but whenever i make a wrong input and then register, they don't gave the validation message, does anyone know how to connect between my registration design with the laravel registration auth?

Answer (score 0):

That is example how to implement it in blade:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#working-with-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention how are you overriding the default registration, I will make an assumption that you are overriding the `register` method from `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` controller. If this is your case then you just have to add a line to your `register` method

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // Add this line at the beginning of your register method
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    // Add your registration code below
}
```

And you should also display the errors inside your template file. Here is how you would display the errors for the `email` field:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">@lang('auth/register.email_address')</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-div">
                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
# add rule 
$rules = [
    'username' => 'required|string|email',
    'password' => 'required',
];

# add custome messages, if needed 
$msg = [
    'username.required' => 'Username is required',
    'password.required' => 'Password is required',
];

# validating those
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $msg);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    # if validation fails
    return Redirect::to('URL')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
else {
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    if (!Auth::attempt([ 'email' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
        # if login fail
        return Redirect::to('URL');
    }
    else {
    # if success
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
}
```

**Might useful**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

to validate the form you can use the below code

**in your controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
            $this->validate($request,[
                    'enq_source'=>'required|not_in:-1',
                    'c_person'=>'required',
                    'p_contact'=>'required',
                    'email1'=>'required',

                ]);

            $enquiry=new Enquiry;
            $enquiry->enq_source=$request->enq_source;
            $enquiry->enq_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->enq_date));
            $enquiry->company_name=$request->company_name;
            $enquiry->c_person=$request->c_person;
            $enquiry->c_designation=$request->c_designation;
            $enquiry->state=$request->st;
            $enquiry->district=$request->District;
            $enquiry->address=$request->address;
            $enquiry->p_contact=$request->p_contact;
            $enquiry->c_contact=$request->c_contact;
            $enquiry->email=$request->email1;
            $enquiry->c_profile=$request->c_profile;
            $enquiry->purpose=$request->purpose;
            $enquiry->sales_person=$request->sales_person;
            if(sizeof($request->product_name)>0){
                $enquiry->product_name=implode(',', $request->product_name);

            }



            $enquiry->quantity=$request->quantity;
            $enquiry->status=$request->status;
            $enquiry->comment=$request->comment1;
            $enquiry->save();

            $request->session()->flash('success', 'Enquiry successfully Added');
            return redirect(route('admin.dashboard'));

    }
```

**and make the view like below**

```
<input id="company_name" name="company_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" value="{{old('company_name')}}">
                      @if ($errors->has('company_name'))
                                <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('company_name') }}</div>
                            @endif
```